# Updating selcted column values of one table with another table

Tags: sql, sql-update, left-join

I have a scenario where I need to copy some particular column values from master_table to the same column of slave_table. Note that slave_table already contains data, I need to update particular fields only based on conditions, which I specify using where clause.

Table structures are below.

Master_table

```
id  zzco1   zzco2   zzco3   zzco4   zzco5   quote_id        quote_option_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   ded     34      6.90     90     sad     10000123        2009090
2   rfg     45      7.90     30     sd      10000256        2008020
3   hji     62      80.90    70     pt      10000963        2009603
4   opp     30      61.90    20     rts     10000785        2007562
```

Slave_table

```
id  zzco1   zzco2   zzco3   zzco4   zzco5   quote_id        quote_option_id     zzco7   zzco8 zzco9
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    null   null    null    null    null    10000123        2009090             cbz     xcc
2    null   null    null    null    null    10000123        2009090             cbz     xcc
3    null   null    null    null    null    10000123        2009090             cbz     xcc
4    null   null    null    null    null    10000256        2008020             szc     zxc
5    null   null    null    null    null    10000256        2008020             szc     zxc
6    null   null    null    null    null    10000256        2008020             szc     zxc
```

expected_ output is below

Slave_table

```
id  zzco1   zzco2   zzco3   zzco4   zzco5   quote_id        quote_option_id     zzco7   zzco8 zzco9
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   ded     34      6.90     90     sad     10000123        2009090             cbz     xcc
2   ded     34      6.90     90     sad     10000123        2009090             cbz     xcc
3   ded     34      6.90     90     sad     10000123        2009090             cbz     xcc
4   rfg     45      7.90     30     sd      10000256        2008020             szc     zxc
5   rfg     45      7.90     30     sd      10000256        2008020             szc     zxc
6   rfg     45      7.90     30     sd      10000256        2008020             szc     zxc
```

based on the `quote_id` and `quote_option_id`, need to copy data from `master_table` to `slave_table`

I tried the below Query, but it's not working as expected. it's storing null values only.

```
UPDATE slav
  SET   slav.zzco1 = mast.zzco1,
slav.zzco2 = mast.zzco2,
slav.zzco3 = mast.zzco3,
slav.zzco4 = mast.zzco4,
slav.zzco5 = mast.zzco5,
FROM slave_table AS slav
  left JOIN master_table AS mast
ON mast.quote_id = slav.quote_id and mast.quote_option_id = slav.quote_option_id
WHERE slav.quote_id = 'quote_id'
  AND slav.quote_option_id= 'quote_option_id';
```

please correct me where I'm going wrong in the query. Any suggestions and leads appreciated.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server, please tag your question with the right tag.

Comment: Try running this as a `select` first.  You have something wrong with the matching conditions, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use INNER JOIN if you want to update rows with the same `quote_id` and `quote_option_id` in the slave tables.